# Where's the _Start a Bounty_ Link

Tags: discussion, bounty

When I looked a few seconds ago, I couldn't find a *start a bounty* link for this [question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/134638/showcase-tex-typography-for-tugs-calendar).

Is there a reason for this?

Comment: What's the bounty history here? Have you simply reached the maximum bounty you can attach to one question?

Comment: @JosephWright I don't know. My last bounty was running for a week before it expired. If you look at the text below the question, it says _question eligible for bounty since Sep 25 '13._

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You have awarded the following bounties already on the [post in question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/134638/5764):

- [500 reputation to Gonzalo Medina](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/208922/5764)
- [500 reputation to Yiannis Lazarides](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/206982/5764)
- [500 reputation to commonhare](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/206733/5764)
- [500 reputation to Sam Whited](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/201499/5764)
- [500 reputation to dcmst](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/200451/5764)
- [500 reputation to ChrisS](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/188649/5764)
- [500 reputation to Paul Gessler](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/188642/5764)
- [1,000 reputation to OSjerick](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/150302/5764)
- [500 reputation to Thérèse](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/151340/5764)
- [500 reputation to mrc](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/150833/5764)
- [2,000 reputation to ChrisS](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/149134/5764)
- [500 reputation to ChrisS](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/149930/5764)
- [500 reputation to WillAdams](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/148383/5764)
- [1,000 reputation to Nicholas Hamilton](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/146178/5764)

Bounties, when chosen, have to [increase at least two-fold](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/105639/168244):

> We now double the minimum "spend" for successive bounties *on the same question by the same user*. So if you started at 50: your next bounty on that question has a minimum of 100, the next 200, the next 400, the next (max).

You started out with awarding the maximum 500, so successive bounties can only be awarded at 500 reputation (the maximum). This is obviously doable by nature of your almost 10K reputation splurge. However, you can also only award the bounty when you have enough reputation. Currently you're at 140:

[image]

Try again when you reach 500. Note that with reputation loss comes privilege loss as well.

Reference: [How does the bounty system work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/16065/168244)

Comment: Thanks (+1). That makes sense.  hadn't noticed that restriction. Odd the awards for the bounties have to increase...

Comment: @MarcvanDongen It makes sense, and it prevents people from sticking a question again and again "with no costs".

Comment: @tohecz With _no_ costs???

Comment: @MarcvanDongen You could get a lot of promotion on the bigger sites with a small bounty (lots of +50 might net enough question upvotes to 'repay' it)

Comment: @MarcvanDongen the minimal bounty is 50, which is "no costs" for many, you've got 1700 users here with 1k rep. Plus what Joseph says, if the question is yours own.

Comment: @JosephWright (and toheckz) I understand that. I'm not looking for attention; just looking for contributions.

Comment: @MarcvanDongen The StackExchange model is based reasonably tightly on the idea of a question with answers where there can be some reasonable ordering of the latter. As such, questions with a constantly growing number of answers are not really well supported (they get auto-flagged at 30 answers, for example). 'Attention' here means 'being promoted' which is what a bounty does.